# Record from either or both microphones on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

The iPhone 4 has two built in microphones, one in the standard place and one sitting next to the headphone jack. I know this new mic is used for noise reduction in calls but it is also used on facetime, videoing, speakerphone calls etc.

I have a valid reason that I want to be able to choose which mic to record from, be it the new one or the old AND even both at same time.

Does anyone know how to route avaudiorecorder so I can choose any of the above options of what is being recorded?

Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for "I have a valid reason". :)

Comment: lol, ok strange thing to say - but hate they way people get knocked down with replies like 'why do you need to do that, what's wrong with the usual one" or "what's the difference between the two - just use one" etc, of which miss the point and are not helpful!

Comment: I got the valid reason also, if I find the solution I will update here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ancient question, but for future reference in case others are looking for the same answer, I'll put some information here. There is a [section in the **AVAudioSession** documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1799/_index.html) that explains that since iOS7, there is a way to do this explicitly:

> Using APIs introduced in iOS 7, developers can perform tasks such as locating a port description that represents the built-in microphone, locating specific microphones like the "front", "back" or "bottom", setting your choice of microphone as the preferred data source, setting the built-in microphone port as the preferred input and even selecting a preferred microphone polar pattern if the hardware supports it. See AVAudioSession.h.

In older OS's, you could only choose the `AVAudioSessionMode` to affect the choice of microphone.